# Can't get response by OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using the code of http://square.github.io/okhttp/. What I want is: I want to get response from a server by post request. Here is the code:

```
package com.codingpractise.www.officemanagement;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView output;
    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//      Initialize the TextView for vertical scrolling
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        output.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    }



    public void sendSalesData(View view) {
        try{
            if(isOnline()){
                //Net connection Ok
               // requestData("http://localhost:1234/track/process/data");

                String json = "{'winCondition':'HIGH_SCORE',"
                        + "'name':'Bowling',"
                        + "'round':4,"
                        + "'lastSaved':1367702411696,"
                        + "'dateStarted':1367702378785,"
                        + "'players':["
                        + "{'name':'" + "Sattar" + "','history':[10,8,6,7,8],'color':-13388315,'total':39},"
                        + "{'name':'" + "Santo" + "','history':[6,10,5,10,10],'color':-48060,'total':41}"
                        + "]}";
                //String response = post("http://localhost:1234/track/process/data", json);
                MainActivity  thisObj = new MainActivity();

                String response = thisObj.post("http://localhost:1234/track/process/data", json);
               System.out.println(response);

               // String  response ="Fuck";
                output.setText(response);
            }
            else{
                output.setText("NO Internet connection!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            output.setText(e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
      String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

When a button is clicked sendSalesData() function will execute. In this function I process post request. When I click on this button then response should be visible on `output` textview object. But i don't get any response from server.

The server response is just simple php echo code:

```
echo 'response from server';
```

But I get nothing when I click on this button. What problems with my code.

Sorry for my bad English. I am very beginner to android app, So if my question is not standard, I am sorry for that.

Comment: where you have call sendSalesData() method ?

Comment: in MainActivity.java file

Answer (score 2):

I Have use this to Post data using okHttp.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
        .add("search", "Jurassic Park")
        .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to import any class for FormEncodingBuilder?

Comment: visit this here you can solve all the thing. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.squareup.okhttp.FormEncodingBuilder

Answer (score 1):

For sending JSON request using OkHttp, follow this method -

Create a class ResponseOKhttp either in your activity or a separate one

```
public class ResponseOKhttp

{
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    public String run(String url, String json) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

}
```

To use the above class for sending request, Just instantiate it where you want it to.

```
ResponseOKhttp example = new ResponseOKhttp();

String response = null;
    try {
        response = example.run(url, json.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("responsegot",response);
```

Comment: This code seems to me perfect. But I can't get any response from server. I  am doing in a wrong track may be. Is there any way to inspect response as like  web application(firebug) ?

Comment: you can use Postman app to check your response from server. http://www.getpostman.com/ ... Just add the JSON string or key value pairs and the URL in postman, set the request type like GET or POST type, send the request and see the response.

Answer (score 0):

try this to post data using okhttp

```
    public static JSONObject uploadImage() {

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            try {

                RequestBody req = new MultipartBody.builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("YOUR_KEY", "your value")
                        .addFormDataPart("YOUR_KEY","your value")).build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("url")
                        .post(req)
                        .build();

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                Log.d("response", "uploadImage:"+response.body().string());

                return new JSONObject(response.body().string());

            } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
```